# runnable that started on a new thread does not stop when removeCallbacks() is called

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have the following below code.

```
//This is global for the activity.
Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {   
               //update the UI
    }
};
```

In my onResume() I am starting a new thread that runs a runnable.

```
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.start();
}
```

My runnable is as follows :

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
                  // some networking stuff 
                  // some db stuff
                  // whatever


        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new Thread(runnable).start();
            }
        }, 30000);
    }
}
```

And I have this inside onPause() :

```
protected void onPause()
    {       
        super.onPause();
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
```

At the end I call the `handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);` so that the `handleMessage(Message msg)` gets called and I do the UI changes, and I repeat the task but starting a new runnable, which starts a new thread that runs the same runnable as this.

Clarification questions :

1. I am starting a new Thread inside my onResume(), which means that the runnable is not running on the UI Thread, however, the handler is being created on the UI thread and is naturally attached to the UI thread. How is the UI is being changed flawlessly ?
2. It is supposed for handler.removeCallbacks(runnable), however, whenever I minized the app, the runnable still keeps on running every 30 seconds. (this might be because it is on a new thread, that is not associated with the Handler created). How can I make it stop ?

Comment: For 2. I'd say it's because you do not remove the same instance, perhaps. See you make a new `Runnable` instance in each `handler.postDelayed` but you seem only to remove one shared instance.

Comment: aha, might be. whats the trick ?

Comment: Don't make a new runnable. Use `this` runnable. And lose the extra Thread. just make that line `handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);`

Comment: I think it would be worthwhile for you to read the documentation for Handler and Runnable closely. Your code looks as through you've assembled a few code samples you found, without fully understanding what they do. You won't need a new thread for what you're doing, unless there's extensive work done in `handleMessage()` -- however, as it currently is, you're doing that work on the UI thread anyway, because a Handler is tied to the thread which instantiates it.

Comment: @323go 100%. I'm a novice, and put this stuff from the bits and pieces I read here and there. You are right the main thing is happening inside the thread. Can you kindly guide the code, to 'what I think' I am doing ? regarding doing the work on the UI thread, I think I am not, because I am not getting any networkOnMainThread exceptions.

Comment: In the code you provided, you don't do anything networky ...

Comment: @Fildor I do. I have had written it as comments inside the runnable. Have a look.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry. Can you say a little more about that "network stuff"?

Comment: @Fildor no worries. What do you think about what 323go has said ? Btw, I will try your approach now. I'll let you know.

Comment: Network stuff = go to server, and get some data as json.

Comment: What 323go says makes absolutely sense. First try without extra threads. If Android gives you an exception, use an AsyncTask or something like that to not block the UI.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38342/discussion-between-tony9099-and-fildor)

Comment: I'm adding an example as answer. I extracted it from working code which does something quite similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int UPDATE = 1;
    public static final int WORK = 2;

    private Handler uiHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case UPDATE:
                // Perform UI updates here
                ....
                // UI Updates done, schedule WORK in 30 seconds:
                this.sendMessageDelayed(this.obtainMessage(WORK), 30000);
                break;
            case WORK:
                new Thread(doWork).start();
                break;

            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }

    };

private WeakReference<Handler> handlerRef = new WeakReference<Handler>( uiHandler );

    private Runnable doWork = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This will run on a different thread.

            // If UI is still around, tell it to update
            Handler ui = handlerRef.get();
            if( ui != null )
                ui.sendEmptyMessage(MainActivity.UPDATE);
        }
    };  

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        uiHandler.removeMessages(WORK);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Resume UI updates in 500ms, allowing UI to settle
        uiHandler.sendMessageDelayed(uiHandler.obtainMessage(WORK), 500);
    }

    ....
}
```

This pattern uses a single Handler on the UI thread. Background work is done in the Runnable, which the ui Handler will post to a new Thread, so avoiding `NetworkOnMainThreadException` and -- more importantly -- unresponsive UI. Further, a new update is scheduled thirty seconds after the background process has completed, to avoid taxing the system with long-running updates. The background thread uses a `WeakReference` to the ui Handler, so if the `Activity` is killed while the thread is working, it won't send UI updates to it.

Comment: upon initial testing, the code runs perfect. Thanks a lot for this. Highly appreciated.

Comment: I should also have noted that if you use this same pattern in multiple Activities, it would be wise to off-load this to a Service, which then submits broadcasts once an update has completed. A Binder could be used in lieu of broadcasts, but it's marginally more complex.

Comment: no this will only happen in my Main Activity. (every 1 minute). Btw, what is the trick with this.obtainMessage(WORK), you are doing this to avoid creating a new Bundle, Message and send the Message like that ?

Comment: Bundles and Messages aren't the same thing (but very similar in function). `obtainMessage(int)` is just a very easy way to create a message on a thread and then setting the `what`. Nice little shortcut provided by the API.

Comment: I know they are the same thing, but you need a Bundle to put it in the Message. - Anyways - I was unaware of this approach. It definitely is a nice little shortcut that does the job quick and fast.

Comment: btw, isnt it better if the weakreference handler is static ?

Comment: If you did, then `uiHandler` would also need to be static, and then the GC could get delayed; not that the current solution will prevent that in all cases.

Comment: well, I am getting this in eclipse : This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur (com.myApp MainActivity.1)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38361/discussion-between-tony9099-and-323go)